# Which will have better quality, an H.264 encoded video with higher bitrate or an H.265 with lower bitrate?

Tags: encoding, h.264, action-cam, h.265, hevc

I got a cheap action camera that allows me to choose the encoding of the video being recorded between H.264 and H.265.

When I set it to H.264, the video's bitrate is set to around 10,000+ kbps. When I set the encoder to H.265, it sets the bitrate to around 5,000-6,000+ kbps.

Aside from that, I have no further control about the quality of the video. So in this scenario, which combination would eventually end up with a higher detailed video?

I'm asking because if I'm being honest, I can't tell the difference between the two and I feel like any difference I see would just be placebo.